# How can I pass multiple arguments/parameters to a function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parameter-passing

I'm trying to use a link to call a Vue-function with 3 arguments/parameters, but it doesn't seem to work. It was working with only one parameter.

I have:

```
<td>
  <a @click="delete('{{$detail->mainID}}, {{$detail->typeID }}, {{$detail->siteID}}')">Delete</a>
</td>

delete: function(mainID,typeID,siteID) {
    ...
}
```

How can I properly pass 3 arguments into my function?

Comment: you're only passing one parameter as a string. You should close single quotes before each `,`

`<a @click="delete('{{$detail->mainID}}', '{{$detail->typeID }}', '{{$detail ->siteID}}')">Delete</a>`

Comment: because of your Quotes, it making them as one arguments.

Comment: Why don't you just do  `delete($detail)`, if all your arguments are props of the same object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with your "a" tag. You need to separate your values like this:

```
<a @click="delete('{{$detail->mainID}}', '{{$detail->typeID }}', '{{$detail->siteID}}')">Delete</a>
```

PS: pay attention to quotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you put all parameters into one quote, it will be seen as one parameter.